# jquery return error msg from php server not showing in div

Tags: php, jquery, post

i have a simple code for js on my side and wanted to return the error msg from my php json server side if there is an error such like custom msg

php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('class/MysqliDb.php');
$db = new Mysqlidb();
$cols = array("card_id","card_os");

$cards = $db->get("cards",null,$cols);
if($db->count >0){
$cards['status'] = 'success';
} else {
$cards['status'] = 'fail';
$cards['error'] = 'fail to insert';
}
echo json_encode($cards);
?>
```

as for my js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.post('./get_cards.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){


 if(msg.status == 'success'){
 $('#cardlist').html(format(msg));                        
 }
 else if(msg.status == 'fail') {
  console.log(msg.error);
 $('#cardlist').html(msg.error);
 }
 },'json');

 } );
```

i am trying to have my #cardlist div to have this error msg 'fail to insert' from my server side. It is not showing the msg in the div but instead when is there is data is populating correctly.

updated with format() function

```
 function format ( d ) {
 var html = null;
 var card_os = null;
 $.each(d,function(k,v){
 if(v.card_os){
  card_os = v.card_os;
  }
 if(v.card_id){
 var card_id = v.card_id;
  html += '<li>'+
          '<h3>'+card_id+'</h3>'+
          '<img src="images/'+card_id+'.jpg" width="100" height="100"'+
          '</li>';
   }
 });
 $('#test_title').html('<h1>test: '+card_os+'</h1>');
 return html;
 }
```

html code

```
<div id="columns" class="grid-4" style="display:block;">
        <ul class="test columns-4">
        <div id="cardlist"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to log what your `msg` contains.

Comment: my msg logs correctly and goes to the 'fail' part but is like not having the error msg shown in my #cardlist div.

Comment: You should use `boolean` values instead.

Comment: still the same, no difference where the message will not be append or html on the cardlist div

Comment: What does `format(msg)` do? note `$('#cardlist').html(format(msg));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86939/discussion-between-kyle-emmanuel-and-user1897151).

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your html codes too? Maybe your div id is wrong or it's a class and you used the wrong tag.

Comment: Try to type $("#cardlist").html("testing") in the developer console in your browser and see if your div gets updated.

Comment: Object { 0: <div#cardlist>, length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → test.php, selector: "#cardlist" }  seems like not having any content in the div

Comment: Does the text in #cardlist change to "testing"?

Comment: my #cardlist div is empty tho originally and this does not add the testing inside the div as well

Comment: created another div on top of that <div id="testerror"></div> and this time it works for that div